# In ASP.NET Core MVC, a controller treats '31/12/2020' as an invalid date

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, datetime

In an ASP.NET MVC application (.NET Core 3.1), I have a controller action method that accepts DateTime parameters. I've noticed that when the date passed to the action method is '31/12/2020' (or the same date in other year), the parameter is set to the DateTime.MinValue. All other dates that I've tried in UK format work correctly (like 01/01/2020).

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetSalesProductsByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    if (fromDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { message = "The date value for the fromDate parameter has not be set" })
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest
        };
    }

    if (toDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { message = "The date value for the toDate parameter has not be set" })
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest
        };
    }

   // Other code omitted as irrelevant
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to have the DateTime parameter accept the date 31/12/2020? Thanks.

Comment: Does 30/12/2020 work? Or any other date that is not valid for a pattern of MM/dd/yyyy, like 13/01/1999? Be careful assuming "it's dd/MM/yyyy" the only other date you say you've tried (01/01/2020) is valid for either dd/MM/yyy or MM/dd/yyyy so it doesn't really prove anything. If you're going to pass dates around as strings, prefer yyyy-MM-dd; it's highly unlikely anyone ever decided to use yyyy-dd-MM so it's fairly safe to say that 2020-10-05 really is 5th oct and not 10th may

Comment: Have you configured [the localization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#localization-middleware) and ensured that a locale is being set appropriately for your users (e.g., by their browser settings via [the Accept-Language settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-accept-language-http-header), or through a [cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cookierequestcultureprovider))?